# 504 Gateway timeout in AWS App runner sometimes

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-app-runner

I installed laravel 10 project at AWS App Runner and connect with github Repo.
I use this laravel as backend api.
Sometimes after deployment, api endpoint returns 504 gateway timeout.
I should click deploy button manually and it starts to work again.
I created custom VPC and deployed app runner on it with RDS.
Why does not this run sometimes?
I should check manually and deploy again every time.
Thanks

Comment: seems like readiness probe returns success when it's not or You don't have heathcheck and readiness endpoins. Make sure readiness and healthcheck endpoints are making sure connections to db or thirdparty are working as expected.

Comment: At this time, login API works, and even the Database record create/edit is working - I could check them on DB directly - DB data is updated or created - but so it means API accepted the request and it finished, but the API is timeout - returns 504 timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first check AWS App Runner Logs, there you can check when 504 Gateway Timeout is occurring.
That issue can happen in really diverse scenarios, such, low resource allocation due to the flood of incoming requests.
I would aslo check the RDS losgs to see if there is somethink weird in it.